# Issue with commenting on Facebook posts with api

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I'm a beginner on Facebook API but after reading up and understanding whatever I could I'm still stuck because I can't find any good documentation that is not outdated.

I'm trying to comment on my own post and I keep getting this error:

**Publishing comments through the API is only available for page access tokens**

I do understand that I require a page access token for the latest version of the API but even after getting the page access token I'm still facing this issue.

Here is a screenshot of my graph API explorer

[image: Facebook graph API explorer]

Here I first clicked on get user access token and gave it all possible permissions. After that I clicked on get page access token and then tried to post the comment.

**Note:** The post was made by my ID and is visible only to me, I am sure that the user ID and post ID is correct because I am able to view its details

I also tried it using python with the token ID above and this code.

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token_id)
#This does give me the post details
#print (graph.get_object(id = my_id +'_10214865328931217'))
graph.put_object(parent_object=my_id+'_10214865328931217',connection_name='comments', message='Test')
```

But I still get the same error. Seems like there is something about the way page access tokens work that I do not understand.

Comment: "all possible permissions" ... why? only use those permissions you actually need, the api reference tells you exactly which ones you need. about the issue: is that a page post you want to comment on?

Comment: I am just experimenting as of now because I'm a complete beginner which is why I gave all the permissions. Plus its an app being used just by my ID. The post is a status update though graph API Explorer by my ID which is visible only to me. After some more research I stumbled upon something like "an app cannot edit non-app posts" I think this may be why this is happening.

Comment: why would you post a comment as page on a user post anyway? i believe that is the issue.

Comment: I tried doing that because when I tried commenting on the post by myself with a user token I got the error saying that I require a page access token

Comment: that´s not what i meant. try commenting on a PAGE post, not a user post. and you can only comment "as page".(that is what a page token means)

Comment: Ok, now it works with a page post. I was actually thinking of creating an app that replies to all the posts on my wall wishing me on my birthday. Isn't that possible through graph API?

Comment: no, of course not. page tokens are the only way to comment, and they are meant to post "as page" (replying to user posts on your page), not "as user". user commenting with the api would be an open gate for spam.

Comment: why not just post a new message on your wall, for replying once for the birthday wishes? that´s how people usually do it if they don´t want to reply to everyone in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the info. And I'm also assuming that unless my app is reviewed and approved, my posts cannot be viewed by other users as well. Yes of course I can post a message on my wall I was just trying something more innovative. Thank you.